# ip route command with source option

Tags: linux, networking

I have multiple interfaces on my system catering to different subnets. I also have a pseudo interface
which is a p-to-p driver for tunneling packets. I was trying to add routes using ip route command to 
use a specific interfaces' source IP when sending the packets out on the tunnel interface.

In this example, i want to use 11.11.11.1 source IP  which is set on eth1.100 when sending packets
to 60.60.60.1 which is reachable over the tunnel. This is how my route table looks like.

```
   /tmp # ip route show
   60.60.60.1 dev tsgw  scope link  src 11.11.11.1  >> Added this route.
   11.11.11.0/24 dev eth1.100  proto kernel  scope link  src 11.11.11.1
   default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth1.4094  metric 10
   192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1.4094  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.3
```

If i ping 60.60.60.1, it still picks my interface through which default route is programmed.

```
PING 60.60.60.1 (60.60.60.1): 56 data bytes
19:35:32.848428 IP 192.168.1.3 > 60.60.60.1: ICMP echo request, id 16986, seq 0, length 64
19:35:33.848621 IP 192.168.1.3 > 60.60.60.1: ICMP echo request, id 16986, seq 1, length 64
19:35:34.848819 IP 192.168.1.3 > 60.60.60.1: ICMP echo request, id 16986, seq 2, length 64
```

Am i doing something wrong with setting the source? Whats the right way to go about this? Basically
i am looking to send all packets taking the tsgw interface to use a specific private source IP.

```
eth1.100  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0B:86:B8:91:10
          inet addr:11.11.11.1  Bcast:11.11.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1602  Metric:1
          RX packets:560 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:97395 (95.1 KiB)  TX bytes:704 (704.0 B)


tsgw      Link encap:Point-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:127.0.0.2  P-t-P:127.0.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:960  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:1121650 (1.0 MiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ping with source interface as eth1.100

**ping 60.60.60.1 -I eth1.100**